# tomlkit: nicely formatted array with inline tables

Tags: python, toml, tomlkit

I am trying to use [tomlkit](https://github.com/sdispater/tomlkit)  0.8.0 to create a TOML from the following data:

```py
data = {
    'stuff': [
        {'a':1, 'b': 2},
        {'c': 3},
        {'a': 4},
    ]
}
```

in this format exactly:

```
stuff = [
    {a = 1, b = 2},
    {c = 3},
    {a = 4}, 
]
```

A simple`print(tomlkit.dumps(data))` creates:

```
[[stuff]]
a = 1
b = 2

[[stuff]]
c = 3

[[stuff]]
a = 4
```

How can this be done is a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found so far is somewhat complicated:

```
doc = tomlkit.document()
a = tomlkit.array()
for x in data['stuff']:
    t = tomlkit.inline_table()
    t.update(x)
    a.add_line(t)
a.append(tomlkit.nl())
doc.add('stuff', a)
print(tomlkit.dumps(doc))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works with tomlkit 0.11 (and probably earlier):

```py
doc = tomlkit.document()
a = tomlkit.array()
for x in data['stuff']:
    t = tomlkit.inline_table()
    t.update(x)
    a.add_line(t)
doc.add('stuff', a.multiline(True))
print(tomlkit.dumps(doc))
```

Using `a.multiline(True)` will return the array in its multiline version. Unlike explicitly adding a new line via `tomlkit.nl()`, there will not be an empty line between the last array entry and its closing bracket, so it should exactly match the required format.